# Threads with independent host environments (c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, environment-variables

I have been doin a research of this topic but i did not find anything.

I have a code in which I am looping a function which each time is in a different thread (`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>>`).

The system works correctly, but inside this function i have to give a specific environment variable value for each thread, and knowing that `std::thread`, even if it is running independently, the host environment is shared, it is not possible to set this environment variable to an independent value (if i use `setenv()` it changes to all the threads).

Unfortunatelly, due to the nature of my need, i cannot solve the problem using a mutex.

So, this is my question. There is any kind of specific thread library (or hidden parameter in `std::thread` or boost) which allows me to set threads maintaining different environment variables for each one?.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need different environment variables for each thread? What is the real problem that's supposed to solve? Have you thought about using *processes* instead of threads?

Comment: Oh and why have pointers to threads? Can't you have a plain `std::vector<std::thread>`? Do you really have shared ownership of the thread objects (if you see the smart pointers from a resource ownership perspective)?

Comment: I need different environment variables because I am running the program as a server which has different clients (each client a different port)  which whon it has to be linked. I have a way to go reconnecting between the diffrerent clients, but is a process quite slow which does not allow me to have a fast updat for each client. 

the std::shared_ptr it is just put because I reused part of the code of the framework on which my script will work with.

Comment: I still don't see the need for environment variables here at all. Will the threads *read* or *write* (or both) the environment? Writing makes no sense unless you use it as a kind of inter-thread communication method, or you need to start child-processes which inherits the environment. And only reading makes no sense either, since the environment is set *once* when your process is created, and can't be modified externally, and then shared among all threads in the process.

Comment: And what is the kind of data you want to store in the environment? Can't you pass the data to each thread as you create it (with C++ and `std::thread` is *very* easy to pass arguments to the thread functions)?

Comment: In order to generate the clients, i need to have this variable set to the port desired (This is how it works the library I am using which generate theses clients). To generate specific variables i know its easy, but i have to modify the backend of the library which I am using

Comment: Okay I get it now. So it's a design-flaw (I would argue) in the framework you're using.

Comment: I don't understand how the different clients set different environment variables? If they are in different processes then don't you really need to read *their* process environments? I am not understanding what is happening here. Usually clients communicate their specifics through the normal client/server communication protocol. What is the reason to want to communicate between process environments outside the normal client/server connection?

Comment: Of course every client is a different process, but the problem is in the generation of the client, which is done from the main program, and reading the main environment variables. The client variables are set internally using functions which uses getenv() function, so, it cannot be set from any other kind of variable.

Comment: I will not consider that exactly a design flaw due to the fact that what I am trying to do is something quite strange and probably the original use was not thought for something like what I am trying to do. But i see you get the point. Thanks anyway for the interest :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for threads to have different environment variables (all threads in the same process share them - there's no way around it).

Why do you need it that way? if it's some config value or similar, then you could store it in a [*thread-local*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) variable.

If you really need a separate environment, you'll have to use multi-processes (instead of threads).

Comment: It is what i was thinking. Thanks anyway. I saw several solutions generating multi processes using sh files, but I wanted something that allowed me a little more dinamism at tghe time of generating a specific number of replicas.